# Portfolio list view after clicking back button

Tags: ajax, get-posts

how would it be possible to get back to the same portfolio listing page, after the clicking browser back button from single portfolio item? Now it goes back to the first page of portfolio listing.

Here's the web link: http://auksodulkes.linasrukas.lt/vestuviniai-ziedai-juvelyras-kaune/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You simply try below code to achieve your requirement. I hope it will work for you.

```
<button onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;">Go Back</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but what I need is that back button would take me to the right portfolio page number (the one I clicked before I came to the product).